# automatically accepting calls in empathy

Tags: c++

I need to customize Empathy 2.28 such that when an incoming call arrives, it's automatically accepted without a window.  The code section lies as:

```
static void
event_channel_process_voip_func (EventPriv *event)
{
  GtkWidget *dialog;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *image;

  if (event->approval->dialog != NULL)
    {
      gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (event->approval->dialog));
      return;
    }

  dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (NULL, 0,
      GTK_MESSAGE_QUESTION, GTK_BUTTONS_NONE, _("Incoming call"));
  gtk_message_dialog_format_secondary_text (
    GTK_MESSAGE_DIALOG (dialog),
      _("%s is calling you, do you want to answer?"),
      empathy_contact_get_name (event->approval->contact));

  gtk_dialog_set_default_response (GTK_DIALOG (dialog),
      GTK_RESPONSE_OK);

  button = gtk_dialog_add_button (GTK_DIALOG (dialog),
      _("_Reject"), GTK_RESPONSE_REJECT);
  image = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name (GTK_STOCK_CANCEL,
    GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON);
  gtk_button_set_image (GTK_BUTTON (button), image);

  button = gtk_dialog_add_button (GTK_DIALOG (dialog),
      _("_Answer"), GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT);

  image = gtk_image_new_from_icon_name (GTK_STOCK_APPLY, GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON);
  gtk_button_set_image (GTK_BUTTON (button), image);

  g_signal_connect (dialog, "response",
      G_CALLBACK (event_manager_call_window_confirmation_dialog_response_cb),
      event->approval);

  gtk_widget_show (dialog);

  event->approval->dialog = dialog;
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
static void
event_channel_process_voip_func (EventPriv *event)
{
   empathy_call_factory_claim_channel( empathy_call_factory_get(),
                                       GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT);
}
```

Comment: tanx sir, but itz not workin. may i knw wat dis call_factory_claim_channel() is for? sir, any other way to solve dis?

Answer (score 1):

```
static void
event_channel_process_voip_func (EventPriv *event)
{
      EmpathyCallFactory *factory = empathy_call_factory_get ();
      empathy_call_factory_claim_channel (factory, event->approval->operation);

}
```

datz all needed.>>>>>!

tanx mike